# How to replace server side rendered elements in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working on an Angular app that's fetching html from an API. The content comes back as a string and I've been rendering it in the Angular templates using `[innerHtml]`.

However, some of the content comes back with html `<object>` elements with data tags in them that include values needed to make additional API calls that will then be used to replace the content in those `<object>` placeholders.

An example of what an API response might look like:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<object type="application/example" data-type="item" data-rel="link" data-codename="test_data"></object>
<h2>Test headline</h2>
```

Once this comes back from the API, I need to make additional calls based on the data-codename value in the `<object>` tag, replace the `<object>` tag with the html that comes back from that API call, and then render the assembled html on the page.

I'm not sure where to start here or what the best approach to take to accomplish something like this would be. I'd appreciate any suggestions of how to go about this.

Comment: Why wouldn't the API render all HTML you need? It's already rendering the rest of the HTML, why not the objects or the HTML based on those objects? Once loaded onto the page, you can do something like `document.querySelectorAll('[data-codename]')` to find all the elements that use the `data-codename` attribute. Once you have the nodelist you can get the values and use them however.

Comment: Thanks for this @daddygames The API works the way it works. I don't have any control over it. I was hoping to find an Angular way of doing this without manipulating the DOM manually.

Comment: Since the elements are coming from an API, there's no "angular way" to get to those objects. Therefore you have to fallback on the DOM. AFAIK

Comment: @daddygames to solve this I created a service to parse the HTML string content before it ever gets output to the DOM. I used the `DOMParser` to create a document object out of it, processed it, made the necessary API calls, and then built up the document with the new content from those API calls. Then I used `XMLSerializer` to return a new HTML string out of the completed document. That final string is what gets output to the DOM by Angular.